# Handling form from different view and passing form validation through session in django

Tags: django

I have a requirement here to build a comment-like app in my django project, the app has a view to receive a submitted form process it and return the errors to where ever it came from. I finally managed to get it to work, but I have doubt for the way am using it might be wrong since am passing the entire validated form in the session.

below is the code

comment/templatetags/comment.py

```
@register.inclusion_tag('comment/form.html', takes_context=True)
def comment_form(context, model, object_id, next):
    """
    comment_form()
        is responsible for rendering the comment form
    """
    # clear sessions from variable incase it was found

    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)

    try:
        request = context['request']
        if request.session.get('comment_form', False):
            form = CommentForm(request.session['comment_form'])


            form.fields['content_type'].initial = 15
            form.fields['object_id'].initial = 2
            form.fields['next'].initial = next
        else:
            form = CommentForm(initial={
                'content_type'  : content_type.id,
                'object_id'     : object_id,
                'next'          : next
            })

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        form = None

    return {
        'form' : form
    }
```

comment/view.py

```
def save_comment(request):
    """
    save_comment:

    """

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # clear sessions from variable incase it was found
        if request.session.get('comment_form', False):
            del request.session['comment_form']


        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.save()
            messages.info(request, _('Your comment has been posted.'))
            return redirect(form.data.get('next'))
        else:

            request.session['comment_form'] = request.POST
            return redirect(form.data.get('next'))

    else:
        raise Http404
```

the usage is by loading the template tag and firing

```
{% comment_form article article.id article.get_absolute_url %}
```

my doubt is if am doing the correct approach or not by passing the validated form to the session. Would that be a problem? security risk? performance issues?

Please advise

**Update**

In response to Pol question. The reason why I went with this approach is because comment form is handled in a separate app. In my scenario, I render objects such as article and all I do is invoke the templatetag to render the form. What would be an alternative approach for my case?

You also shared with me the django comment app, which am aware of but the client am working with requires a lot of complex work to be done in the comment app thats why am working on a new one.

Comment: I dont see the point to pass the form in to the session. Why would you do this? Just return response to template with the validated form in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see the problem with security, except situation when you using cookies for stroring session. The performance depends on what kind of session backand you are using as well.  But I cant find the point why are you complicating things!

And I dont thing that touching session in template tag is a good idea at all.

And maybe Take a look at django [Comments Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/)

**Update:**

Ok. I cant see the problems in this approach except complication. For example in my project, i'm using ajax to send data and validate it right in the comments view, therefore I do not require to redirect to original page. Other thing is that I pass the initialized Form in article view, so i'm not using templatetags.

Can provide you with my approche for example purposes:

```
from forms import CommentForm
from models import Comment
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.utils import simplejson
from etv_persons.person.models import Person
from django.contrib import messages

def create_comment(request,slug):
    if request.method != 'POST' or not request.POST or request.user.is_anonymous():
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Доступ запрещен')

    person = get_object_or_404(Person,slug=slug)
    form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        Comment.objects.create(user_id=request.user.id, person=person,text=form.cleaned_data['text'])
        if request.is_ajax(): 
            msg={'msg': 'Cement was send',}
        else: 
            messages.info(request, 'COmment was send.')
    else:
        if request.is_ajax(): msg={'msg': 'Error.',}
        else: messages.info(request, 'Error.')
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(msg),content_type='application/json')
    else:  
        return redirect('person_details',**{"slug":slug,"ptype":person.type})
```

And in the article view we just do:

```
response['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
```

And yes, I do not validate the comments form. There is no reason. Just one text input.

Comment: Hi Pol, I just updated my question and wrote down the reason why am going with this approach. I also updated the code with latest, please advise on weather you think my approach is good or if there is alternatives?